# Динамическое добавление и копирование полей

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Имеется три поля:

```
поле1
поле2 
поле3
поле4
Добавить поле (кнопка)
Скопировать (кнопка)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*поле1* - данные(инфа)

*поле2* - это дата(просто дата к примеру в формате 19.02.2015 да в любом не суть)

*поле3*- сколько раз нужно повторить поле!

*поле4* - через сколько дней

*Добавить поле* - при нажатии на данную кнопку ничего не копируется, просто динамически в форму добавляются все поля (*поле1*, *поле2*, *поле3*, *поле4* и кнопка *скопировать*).

*Скопировать* - при нажатии *скопировать* проверяются поля *поле3* и *поле4*, и вниз под данным полем копируется поля *поле1* и *поле2*

Еще кнопка *Удалить* - удаляет 1 элемент и все дочерние (скопированные) элементы данного поля...

А так же как это чудо потом считать пост запросом?

Пока смог сделать (точнее, переделать под себя) динамическое добавление полей.

Answer (score 1):

Готовое решение http://jsfiddle.net/zwxdd43v/4/

Что касается обработки на сервере, код нужно обернуть в *form*.
Обратите внимание на атрибуты у *input*. Формат:

```
table_data[%n][cell_name]
где table_data - общий массив (на стороне сервера)
[%n] - массив 0..n
```

Comment: спасибо большое, ваш вариант частично подходит( там суть чтобы при нажатии скопировать появлялись поля изсходя из полей 3 и 4, то есть к примеру есть число 5.02.2015 в поле 3 у нас введено "2" , а в поле 4 введено 2 то есть, а в поле 4 введено "5" он повторит (скопирует данный материал) 2 раза и к данной дате будет инкрементированно по 5 дней в каждом поле(извините не верно изложил первый раз мысль) P.S если вас не затруднит помогите

Comment: За то что уже сделали огромное спасибо!

Comment: Постройте пожалуйста грамотно свое предложение, с ясной последовательностью мыслий. Я из тонкостей еще в основном вопросе ни чего не понял. Так же и в комментарии ни чего не понял!

Comment: мы имеем 4 поля  последние два поля(поля под номером 3 и 4 это количество повторений и через сколько дней повторять соответственно). К примеру во 2поле(поле даты введена дата) 02.05.2015 в 3м поле введено кол-во повторений 2, а в поле номер 3 введено через 5 дней. То есть при нажатии кнопки скопировать должны скопировать поля вниз с инкрементацией даты +5 в каждом

Comment: До конца не поможет ни кто?